# Create custom form above grid in magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

As per my client requirement, i need to display form above custom grid having 3 input fields and need to perform filter on submit this form.

I have created grid with my custom collection with default magento 1.9 standard

Comment: Could you please post code that is used to display Grid